# What is a suitable WAI-ARIA role attribute for a map element

Tags: google-maps, accessibility, wai-aria

In my webpage, I have half of it being a map display using Google maps. What `aria-role` should I add to that `canvas` element which is displaying the map? I have looked at [WAI-ARIA docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#role_definitions) for possible role definitions and the closest I found is `widget`.

What would be a suitable `aria-role` for a map on the page?

Comment: Why would you want to change the role?  If the map is a `<canvas>`, then it already has appropriate semantics.  The `role` attribute should be used when the semantics of the native element are not correct (e.g. when a `<span>` is actually a button).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using google maps, you should use `role="application"` because it is possible to use a screen reader to interact with the map and according to the ARIA spec site the application role is for:

> A structure containing one or more focusable elements requiring user
>   input, such as keyboard or gesture events, that do not follow a
>   standard interaction pattern supported by a widget role.

This is especially true for users who are not blind but have low vision and can actually benefit from the map.

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#application

Comment: this worked best in my case <div tabindex="0" id="map" role="application" aria-label="Map with restaurants"></div>

Answer (score 0):

Is a Google Map something accessible for blind people? No.

The answer to that question  give you some clue : give it the `presentation` role and `aria-hidden=true` attribute. You should give a correct replacement for the missing information like a full textual itinerary if your map describe an itinerary.

Eg:

```
<div role="presentation" aria-hidden="true">`<!-- my non accessible widget here -->`</div>
<div>Visit us at our store, Penny Lane, 22, Liverpool<br />
     Liverpool City bus, Line 3</div>
```

*Note: Widget is an abstract role you can't give to an element.*

**EDIT: This will remove the ability for a screenreader to interact with the canvas, both from keyboard and mouse, which may not be suitable for illiterate people using a screenreader for instance** *(when the canvas has better accessibility features than Google Maps')*. If you really want to give access to an accessible canvas, do not change the native semantic, otherwise, in this case, place a link before to jump the canvas, specifying that it has very uninuitive keyboard support and may not work with the mouse.

Comment: I disagree with this answer for many reasons.  First, accessibility is not just about blind people.  Second, if the Google map is an interactive widget and not just an image, I'm not even sure your "no" is correct (https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6396990?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).  Third, `role="presentation"` is for removing native semantics, which the question stated was a canvas, so there would be no need to remove it.  Fourth, putting `role="presentation"` on a non-semantic `div` element is redundant and serves no purpose at all.

Comment: @SteveRepsher Accessibility is not about blind people, but aria and roles are, today, elements only visible to screenreader users (for whom a textual alternative, or an address is a better choice). Roles are inherited. When your put a role on a `div`, all elements inside this `div` will inherit this role, and I assumed the  tuser had no control on the `canvas` code

Comment: @SteveRepsher And, concerning Google Maps, the accessibility features requiring multiple unintuitive keystrokes to find informations about a place is keyboard accessible, but this is not "Accessibility". We have no control on the information Google maps will give to the user, and a plain comprehensive english text is a better choice.

Comment: ARIA helps people with various disabilities using different assistive technologies.  Furthermore, far from all screen reader users are blind.  Taking this back to your answer, you're recommending that the choice be taken away from the user to interact with it.  I'm not arguing against also providing a textual equivalent if possible, but hiding a major piece of content is not good accessibility.

Comment: And, yes, the presentation role will inherit, but my argument is still that removing the semantic meaning of the canvas serves to decrease accessibility and would be a WCAG 1.3.1 failure.  It's like putting `role="presentation"` on an `img` just because you gave it an `alt` attribute.

Comment: @SteveRepsher You make a good point about the screenreader not  being used only by non blind people (illiterate for instance). I would perfectly agree with all your arguments if we were not talking about the bad support Google Maps has for accessibility, and the totally unintuitive keyboard support it has. But illiterate can use a mouse, that's true. I edited my answer