# Proper use of ARIA role for Google Maps

Tags: html, google-maps, wai-aria

Which proper ARIA role should I use for Google Maps application?

```html
<section id="map-container">
    <div id="map" role="map"></div>
```

```html
<main id="maincontent">
    <section id="map-container">
      <div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for here is `role="application"` because users can interact with the map using a screen reader, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I did it!

Comment: Thank you and btw, there's more information on [this answer regarding ARIA for general maps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49015889/6225838).

Answer (score 1):

Maps can be challenging to make accessible.  It depends what your map is used for.  I just read this blog this morning about making an accessible google map - https://equalentry.com/accessible-maps-on-the-web/

As for your specific question, there is no "map" `role`.

Using a `role="region"` with an `aria-label` (and possibly `aria-describedby`) can help to define your map area.